# Page scroller like SQL Designer

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a page scroller with jquery like SQL Designer panel? Here is an image of it: http://screensnapr.com/v/jX0Pk1.png

Link: http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/

Please see at right bottom that panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've put together a jsfiddle which should get you 99% there. I hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/rNNzb/2/

I used a combination of jquery ui draggable with jquery scrollTop and scrollLeft as well as some simple viewport calculations.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks a lot for this, just my second week learning Jquery library :)